# WhenAll vs WaitAll in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm trying to understand how `WaitAll` and `WhenAll` works and have following problem. There are two possible ways to get a result from a method:

1. `return Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result.SelectMany(r=> r);`
2. `return tasks.Select(t => t.Result).SelectMany(r => r).ToArray();`

If I understand correctly, the second case is like calling `WaitAll` on `tasks` and fetching the results after that.

It looks like the second case has much better performance. I know that the proper usage of `WhenAll` is with `await` keyword, but still, i'm wondering why there is so big difference in performance for these lines.

After analyzing the flow of the system I think I've figured out how to model the problem in a simple test application (test code is based on I3arnon answer):

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(n => Task.Run(() => Compute(n)));

        var baseTasks = new Task[100];
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            baseTasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                tasks.Select(t => t.Result).SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
            });

        }
        Task.WaitAll(baseTasks);
        Console.WriteLine("Select - {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

        baseTasks = new Task[100];
        stopwatch.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            baseTasks[i] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result.SelectMany(result => result).ToList();
            });

        }
        Task.WaitAll(baseTasks);
        Console.WriteLine("Task.WhenAll - {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
```

It looks like the problem is in starting tasks from other tasks (or in `Parallel` loop). In that case `WhenAll` results in much worse performance of the program. Why is that?

Comment: The second one has deferred execution, and will only be evaluated when you iterate over the resulting `IEnumerable`. Are you sure your tasks are actually started?

Comment: @Chips_100 the original sample uses `ToArray` so it won't have deferred execution

Comment: @Richard - I must admit that at the beginning I forgot to add ToArray. I've editted the question so this is in place now.

Comment: Combining `Parallel.ForEach` with `Task` as you do in your Gist is not something I can recommend. Use `Parallel.ForEach` if you can to maximize performance but if that is impossible and you have to start `Task`'s then there is no point in doing that in a heavily optimized and partitioned parallel loop.

Comment: @bryl: I highly suggest that you include the relevant code in your question to make it self contained instead of linking to another site. The link may decay and even if it does not having to switch context to understand both question and answers is somewhat disruptive.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I did as You suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are starting tasks inside a `Parallel.ForEach` loop which you should avoid. The whole point of `Paralle.ForEach` is to parallelize many small but intensive computations across the available CPU cores and starting a task is not an intensive computation. Rather it creates a task object and stores it on a queue if the task pool is saturated which it quickly will be with 1000 tasks being starteed. So now `Parallel.ForEach` competes with the task pool for compute resources.

In the first loop that is quite slow it seems that the scheduling is suboptimal and very little CPU is used probably because of `Task.WhenAll` inside the `Parallel.ForEach`. If you change the `Parallel.ForEach` to a normal for loop you will see a speedup.

But if you code really is as simple as a `Compute` function without any state carried forward between iterations you can get rid of the tasks and simply use `Parallel.ForEach` to maximize performance:

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, (i, s) =>
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(n => Compute(n)).SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
});
```

As to why `Task.WhenAll` performs much worse you should realize that this code

```
tasks.Select(t => t.Result).SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
```

will not run the tasks in parallel. The `ToList` basically wraps the iteration in a `foreach` loop and the body of the loop creates a task and then waits for the task to complete because you retrieve the `Task.Result` property. So each iteration of the loop will create a task and then wait for it to complete. The 1000 tasks are executed one after the other and there is very little overhead in handling the tasks. This means that you do not need the tasks which is also what I have suggested above.

On the other hand, the code

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result.SelectMany(result => result).ToList();
```

will start all the tasks and try to execute them concurrently and because the task pool is unable to execute 1000 tasks in parallel most of these tasks are queued before they are executed. This creates a big management and task switch overhead which explains the bad performance.

With regard to the final question you added: If the only purpose of the outer task is to start the inner tasks then the outer task has no useful purpose but if the outer tasks are there to perform some kind of coordination of the inner tasks then it might make sense (perhaps you want to combine `Task.WhenAny` with `Task.WhenAll`). Without more context it is hard to answer. However, your question seems to be about performance and starting 100,000 tasks may add considerable overhead.

`Parallel.ForEach` is a good choice if you want to perform 100,000 independent computations like you do in your example. Tasks are very good for executing concurrent activities involving "slow" calls to other systems where you want to wait for and combine results and also handle errors. For massive parallelism they are probably not the best choice.

Comment: That looks like a good answer, but take a look at the second case. Here we have standard `for` loop in which we start tasks that in turn enumerate our suqence of another tasks. Again: `WhenAll` performs much worse. Could you share your thoughts about this case?

Comment: @bryl: I have edited my answer in an attempt to explain why `Task.WhenAll` is slow.

Comment: I have edited my question by one more example: now I'm starting all the tasks immediately. But it looks like your suggestion is correct:  probably task scheduler somehow knows, that tasks are very "small" and tries to run them one by one in a synchronous manner.

Comment: @bryl: In the first loop that is faster you are only starting the next task when the previous has completed. Retrieving `Task.Result` will block and wait for the task to complete and that is done inside the `foreach` loop that `ToList` essentially is. So the tasks are executed synchronously as a result of this code.

Comment: Take a look at "Part 2" of the question. Here `ToArray` in property starts all the tasks immediately

Comment: @bryl: `ToArray` like `ToList` pulls the elements using a `foreach` loop and the body of this loop will get `Task.Result` for every task. So the tasks will be created and executed in sequence and not in parallel. You can verify this be creating a small example with a forced delay in the task and some `Console.WriteLine` statements to see the tasks execute.

Comment: Notice that I'm using `ToArray` before fetching `t.Result` in the "Part 2" of the question. Can I rewrite it somehow to make it more obvious?

Comment: @bryl: Sorry, got it. Perhaps all the tasks have completed by the time `Task.WhenAll` is called? If you look at the source code for `Task.WhenAll` it has an optimization where completed tasks are handled much faster. If all these experiments are an attempt to understand the inner workings of the task pool scheduler you can probably get much better information from an in depth explanation if that exists or simply by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Your test is way too complicated so I've made my own. Here's a simple test that incorporates your `Consume` method:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Repeat(int.MaxValue, 10000).Select(n => Task.Run(() => Compute(n)));

    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Result.SelectMany(result => result).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Task.WhenAll - {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

    stopwatch.Restart();
    tasks.Select(t => t.Result).SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("Select - {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
}

private static List<int> Compute(int seed)
{
    var results = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        results.Add(seed * i);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Output:

```
Task.WhenAll - 00:00:01.2894227
Select - 00:00:01.7114142
```

However if I use `Enumerable.Repeat(int.MaxValue, 100)` the output is:

```
Task.WhenAll - 00:00:00.0205375
Select - 00:00:00.0178089
```

Basically the difference between the options is if you're blocking once or blocking for each element. Blocking once is better when there are many elements, but for few blocking for each one could be better.

Since there ins't really a big difference and, you care about performance only when you're dealing with many items and logically you want to proceed when all the tasks completed I recommend using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: I've removed the deffered execution but still the problem occurs. Any other ideas? Still line number 2 causes better system performance.

Comment: Added full reproduction. Take a look at edited question.

Comment: That is nicely implemented. However, please notice, that right now the question is about starting tasks inside a Parallel loop - that is a scenario where the problem occurs. I have updated the code on Gist according to your implementation. See [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1e461c3a411a9be0d36e)

Comment: @bryl well, this answers the original question. If you have a new question you should post a separate one.